# Rails: How can I prevent the deletion of the last related item?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

If a user tries to delete the last photo from an album, it should not be deleted and the user should be presented with an error.

The following code works in that it prevents the deletion, but the error message is never presented to the user and the controller redirects as if the action has been successful.

Where am I going wrong?

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos,
    :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => :all_blank
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :album
  before_destroy :do_not_delete_last_photo

  def do_not_delete_last_photo
    if album.photos.size == 1
      errors.add(:base, 'Cannot delete the last photo')
      return false
    end
  end
end

class AlbumsController < ApplicationController
  def update
    @album = Album.find(params[:id])
    if @album.update_attributes(params[:album])
      redirect_to albums_path, :notice => 'Album has been updated'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be wrong, but I think you don't get the error, because the `do_not_delete_last_photo` method is not a validation.

As far as I know, rails does not run validations on `destroy`. So instead you could use exceptions. I haven't used them yet, so the code is just what I figured from the docs.

Change the `errors.add` to `raise LastPhotoDeletionError, "Cannot delete the last photo"`

I guess, you should create the class

```
LastPhotoDeleteionError < StandardError
end
```

and put it in the last_photo_deletion_error.rb in the lib folder.
After that, in the controller you should do

```
rescue_from YourErrorClass do |exception|
  flash[:error] = "Cannot delete the last photo" # can't figure a way to access the message you set with `raise`
  render :edit
end
```